# IO Exception while running K-means clustering using mahout and hadoop jar

Tags: java, hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I am trying to run a clustering program using Mahout.Following is my java code which I am using

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedVectorWritable;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.Cluster;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver;
import org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure;
import org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;

public class ClusteringDemo {

    public static final double[][] points = { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 1, 2 },
            { 2, 2 }, { 3, 3 }, { 8, 8 }, { 9, 8 }, { 8, 9 }, { 9, 9 } };

    public static void writePointsToFile(List<Vector> points, String fileName,
            FileSystem fs, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
        Path path = new Path(fileName);
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf, path,
                LongWritable.class, VectorWritable.class);
        long recNum = 0;
        VectorWritable vec = new VectorWritable();
        for (Vector point : points) {
            vec.set(point);
            writer.append(new LongWritable(recNum++), vec);
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    public static List<Vector> getPoints(double[][] raw) {
        List<Vector> points = new ArrayList<Vector>();
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
            double[] fr = raw[i];
            Vector vec = new RandomAccessSparseVector(fr.length);
            vec.assign(fr);
            points.add(vec);
        }
        return points;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int k = 3;
        List<Vector> vectors = getPoints(points);
        File testData = new File("/home/vishal/testdata");
        if (!testData.exists()) {
            testData.mkdir();
        }
        testData = new File("/home/vishal/testdata/points");
        if (!testData.exists()) {
            testData.mkdir();
        }
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        writePointsToFile(vectors, "/home/vishal/testdata/points/file1", fs,
                conf);

        Path path = new Path("/home/vishal/testdata/clusters/part-00000");
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf, path,
                Text.class, Cluster.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            Vector vec = vectors.get(i);
            Cluster cluster = new Cluster(vec, i,
                    new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());
            writer.append(new Text(cluster.getIdentifier()), cluster);

        }
        writer.close();
        KMeansDriver.run(conf, new Path("/home/vishal/testdata/points"),
                new Path("/home/vishal/testdata/clusters"), new Path(
                        "/home/vishal/output"), new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(),
                0.001, 10, true, false);

        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs, new Path(
                "/home/vishal/output/" + Cluster.CLUSTERED_POINTS_DIR
                        + "/part-m-00000"), conf);
        IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
        WeightedVectorWritable value = new WeightedVectorWritable();
        while (reader.next(key, value)) {
            System.out.println(value.toString() + " belongs to cluster "
                    + key.toString());
        }
        reader.close();

    }

}
```

But when i run it ,it starts executing normally but at the end gives me an error..
Following is stack trace which I am getting when I am running it.

```
13/05/30 09:49:22 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/05/30 09:49:22 INFO kmeans.KMeansDriver: Input: /home/vishal/testdata/points Clusters In: /home/vishal/testdata/clusters Out: /home/vishal/output Distance: org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure
13/05/30 09:49:22 INFO kmeans.KMeansDriver: convergence: 0.0010 max Iterations: 10 num Reduce Tasks: org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable Input Vectors: {}
13/05/30 09:49:22 INFO kmeans.KMeansDriver: K-Means Iteration 1
13/05/30 09:49:22 INFO common.HadoopUtil: Deleting /home/vishal/output/clusters-1
13/05/30 09:49:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@15fc40c
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/05/30 09:49:23 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/05/30 09:49:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@15ed659
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 185 bytes
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
13/05/30 09:49:26 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to /home/vishal/output/clusters-1
13/05/30 09:49:27 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/05/30 09:49:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
13/05/30 09:49:29 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 21
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=474
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Clustering
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Converged Clusters=1
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=3328461
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=3422872
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=443
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=189
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=9
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=6
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=531
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=325713920
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=104
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=9
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=3
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=3
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=3
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=3
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=9
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO kmeans.KMeansDriver: K-Means Iteration 2
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO common.HadoopUtil: Deleting /home/vishal/output/clusters-2
13/05/30 09:49:30 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0002
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@13f136e
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/05/30 09:49:30 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0002_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/05/30 09:49:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0002_m_000000_0' done.
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@d6b059
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 124 bytes
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0002_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0002_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
13/05/30 09:49:33 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0002_r_000000_0' to /home/vishal/output/clusters-2
13/05/30 09:49:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/05/30 09:49:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
13/05/30 09:49:36 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0002_r_000000_0' done.
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0002
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 20
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=364
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=6658544
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=6844248
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=443
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=128
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=9
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=4
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=531
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=525074432
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=104
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=9
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=2
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=2
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=2
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=2
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=9
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO kmeans.KMeansDriver: K-Means Iteration 3
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO common.HadoopUtil: Deleting /home/vishal/output/clusters-3
13/05/30 09:49:37 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0003
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@988707
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/05/30 09:49:37 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0003_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/05/30 09:49:38 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0003_m_000000_0' done.
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@6214f5
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 124 bytes
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0003_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0003_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
13/05/30 09:49:40 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0003_r_000000_0' to /home/vishal/output/clusters-3
13/05/30 09:49:41 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/05/30 09:49:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
13/05/30 09:49:43 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0003_r_000000_0' done.
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0003
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 21
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=364
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Clustering
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Converged Clusters=2
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=9988052
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=10265506
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=443
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=128
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=9
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=4
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=531
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=724434944
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=104
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=9
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=2
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=2
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=2
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=2
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/05/30 09:49:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=9
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Target /home/vishal/output/clusters-3-final/clusters-3 is a directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:359)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkDest(FileUtil.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.rename(RawLocalFileSystem.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.rename(ChecksumFileSystem.java:425)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClustersMR(KMeansDriver.java:322)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClusters(KMeansDriver.java:239)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:154)
    at com.ClusteringDemo.main(ClusteringDemo.java:80)
```

What can be the reason ??

Thanks

Comment: You really need to **start reading the error messages**. Obviously a directory exists than is not supposed to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what `KMeansDriver` is trying to do:

```
Path finalClustersIn = new Path(output, AbstractCluster.CLUSTERS_DIR + (iteration-1) + "-final");
FileSystem.get(conf).rename(new Path(output, AbstractCluster.CLUSTERS_DIR + (iteration-1)), finalClustersIn);
```

As you can see, it has converged after 3 iterations and is trying to merge the result of the 3rd iteration in directory **clusters-3** into **clusters-3-final** to show it is finished.

Now the `rename` method of `FileSystem` does a check before actually renaming to ensure it's not trying to rename to a directory that already exists. And as a matter of fact it looks like you already have this directory **clusters-3-final**, probably from a previous run.

Removing this directory should fix your issue, you can do it via command-line with:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /home/vishal/output/clusters-3-final
```

Or since it looks like you're running your job in local mode:

```
rm -rf /home/vishal/output/clusters-3-final
```

To avoid this kind of issues, I would recommend using a unique output directory everytime you run your analysis, you could for example take the current date and append it to the filename of your output `Path`, for example using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

**EDIT**: For your second issue about:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: wrong value class: 0.0: null is not class org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedPropertyVectorWritable at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:1932) at com.ClusteringDemo.main(ClusteringDemo.java:90)
```

you are actually suffering from a conflict between Mahout versions because older Mahout versions used `WeightedVectorWritable` while more recent ones use `WeightedPropertyVectorWritable`. To fix it, simply change the declaration of your `value` variable from:

```
WeightedVectorWritable value = new WeightedVectorWritable();
```

to:

```
WeightedPropertyVectorWritable value = new WeightedPropertyVectorWritable();
```

Comment: Hi Charles............Thanks .But what I understood from your explanation is that  it is due to the presence of directory that the program is terminating at the point of third cluster..   So I deleted the directory and ran the code again..           But still the same problem prevails.............I think I have done something else which is not required ...Is it so?....Actually I am just beginner in this regard.       So thats why the confusion?  Thanks

Comment: Actually it looks like you're running your job in local mode, can you remove this directory on your local disk and try again?

Comment: Thanks Got it>but now its thwoing the following exception;;;

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: wrong value class: 0.0: null is not class org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedPropertyVectorWritable
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:1932)
 at com.ClusteringDemo.main(ClusteringDemo.java:90)

Comment: It's better now your K-Means job finishes successfully, you are just having issues reading the output. Can you check if `/home/vishal/output/clusteredPoints/part-m-00000" exists?

Comment: Hi Charles....Thanks   The specified file is there ,but it cannot be open.....

Comment: The header of the sequence file contain the key/value types, can you cat the beginning of this file and paste it here to see if the types match?

Comment: Hi Charles  when I do cat part-m-00000  following output is displayed     cat part-m-00000
SEQ org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedPropertyVectorWritablerR=L��c��R����C?�?�?�distance1.1313708498984762C?�@?�distance0.8246211251235319C@?�?�distance0.8246211251235319C@@?�distance0.2828427124746191C?�distance1.6970562748477138C@ @ ?�distance0.7071067811865476C@ @"?�distance0.7071067811865476C@"@ ?�distance0.7071067811865476C@"@"?�distance0.7071067811865476vishal@vishal:~/output/clusteredPoints$          Thanks

Comment: You are actually attempting to read the wrong value type - see my updated answer which should fix your issue.